# Counter script not outputting anything

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

I wrote code in JavaScript for a counter to be output in my HTML webpage, but nothing is being printed. Where is my logic wrong?

```
<script>
function calCountDown(){
    var temp = new Date("Dec 11, 2022"); //makes an object 'temp' with current date and time
    var deadline = temp.getTime();     //stores the deadline time
    temp= new Date();                   //stores the object of current date and time
    var currentTime = temp.getTime();   //gets the current time

    var timeDifference = deadline - currentTime;

    var day = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000*60*60*24));       //calculates the difference in days from today till deadline
    var hour = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000*60*60*24))/(1000*60*60));   //calculates the difference in hours from today till deadline
    var minute = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000*60*60))/(1000*60));   //calculates the difference in minutes from today till deadline
    var sec = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000*60))/1000);      //calculates the difference in seconds from today till deadline

    //THIS WILL OUTPUT THE TIME EVERYTIME THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    if(timeDifference < 0){
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "ENDED !!!";
    }
}

 var x = setInterval(calCountDown(), 1000);  

</script>
```

Comment: Is there an error in your console?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:java] tag on your JavaScript questions. They are unrelated languages.

Comment: Your deadline and currentTime variable will hold the same value, so the difference will always be 0, so your if statement won’t pass

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of variables with incorrect names on this line:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
```

I think it should be:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = day + "d " + hour + "h " + minute + "m " + sec + "s ";
```

Also, you had the same value on the `deadline` and `currentTIme` variables.

I have changed it on the example below, and you can see the it outputs the time to the #demo:

```js
function calCountDown() {
  var temp = new Date("Dec 11, 2022"); //makes an object 'temp' with current date and time
  var deadline = temp.getTime(); //stores the deadline time
  var currentTime = new Date(); //gets the current time

  var timeDifference = deadline - currentTime;

  var day = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); //calculates the difference in days from today till deadline
  var hour = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)); //calculates the difference in hours from today till deadline
  var minute = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); //calculates the difference in minutes from today till deadline
  var sec = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000); //calculates the difference in seconds from today till deadline

  //THIS WILL OUTPUT THE TIME EVERYTIME THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = day + "d " + hour + "h " + minute + "m " + sec + "s ";

  if (timeDifference < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "ENDED !!!";
  }
}

var x = setInterval(calCountDown, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()` in your `setInterval` call:

```
var x = setInterval(calCountDown, 1000);
```

`setInterval` takes a function itself (or a string), you were passing it the *return value* from your function, which in this case is `undefined`.

For clarity, you were executing `setInterval(undefined, 1000)`.

### Further Opportunity to Learn

One of my most useful skills as a web developer is using the in-browser JavaScript debugger to step thru the code, set breakpoints, inspect variable values, etc.

I'd recommend you start using your [JavaScript debugger](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=browser+javascript+debugger+tutorial&t=ffab&ia=web) to help understand what's going on in your code. Not just here, but any time you're not understanding what's going on in the code. Debuggers come with every major browser without needing any addons.